# What is the quickest way to get a number with unique digits in python?

Tags: python, performance

Lemme clarify:

What would be the fastest way to get every number with all unique digits between two numbers. For example, 10,000 and 100,000.

Some obvious ones would be 12,345 or 23,456. I'm trying to find a way to gather all of them.

```
for i in xrange(LOW, HIGH):
  str_i = str(i)
  ...?
```

Comment: I understand you want both `12345` and `54321` in your results?

Comment: The *fastest* way? Probably to list them out in the source code... Something tells me you are not looking for the fastest way.

Comment: I'm doing a different brute force to the crypt-arithmetic than the normal ways, I think I am.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```py
from itertools import permutations

result = [
    a * 10000 + b * 1000 + c * 100 + d * 10 + e
    for a, b, c, d, e in permutations(range(10), 5)
    if a != 0
]
```

I used the fact, that:

- numbers between `10000` and `100000` have either 5 or 6 digits, but only 6-digit number here does not have unique digits,
- `itertools.permutations` creates all combinations, with all orderings (so both `12345` and `54321` will appear in the result), with given length,
- you can do permutations directly on sequence of integers (so no overhead for converting the types),

**EDIT**:

Thanks for accepting my answer, but here is the data for the others, comparing mentioned results:

```py
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> stmt1 = '''
a = []
for i in xrange(10000, 100000):
    s = str(i)
    if len(set(s)) == len(s):
        a.append(s)
'''
>>> stmt2 = '''
result = [
    int(''.join(digits))
    for digits in permutations('0123456789', 5)
    if digits[0] != '0'
]
'''
>>> setup2 = 'from itertools import permutations'
>>> stmt3 = '''
result = [
    x for x in xrange(10000, 100000)
    if len(set(str(x))) == len(str(x))
]
'''
>>> stmt4 = '''
result = [
    a * 10000 + b * 1000 + c * 100 + d * 10 + e
    for a, b, c, d, e in permutations(range(10), 5)
    if a != 0
]
'''
>>> setup4 = setup2
>>> timeit(stmt1, number=100)
7.955858945846558
>>> timeit(stmt2, setup2, number=100)
1.879319190979004
>>> timeit(stmt3, number=100)
8.599710941314697
>>> timeit(stmt4, setup4, number=100)
0.7493319511413574
```

So, to sum up:

- [solution no. 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18732321/548696) took `7.96 s`,
- solution no. 2 (my original solution) took `1.88 s`,
- [solution no. 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18732415/548696) took `8.6 s`,
- solution no. 4 (my updated solution) took `0.75 s`,

Last solution looks around 10x faster than solutions proposed by others.

Note: My solution has some imports that I *did not* measure. I assumed your imports will happen once, and code will be executed multiple times. If it is not the case, please adapt the tests to your needs.

**EDIT #2**: I have added another solution, as operating on strings is not even necessary - it can be achieved by having permutations of real integers. I bet this can be speed up even more.

Comment: Will this be faster? The len(set(str)) == len(s) method is humming along rather slowly.

Comment: Nice, except that you do have to exclude numbers starting with zeroes.

Comment: @SetSlapShot: What range are you operating over?

Comment: @nneonneo: Good advice, I have added a check.

Comment: For my case, 10,000,000 to 100,000, 000

Comment: It's also important that I do want 01234567 to be a valid number in my final set.

Comment: @SetSlapShot: `1,234,567` is _not_ between `10,000,000` and `100,000,000`.

Comment: +1 For including `timeit` results for *all* answers to offer the OP a good comparison.

Comment: @SetSlapShot: I have updated my answer with solution that works around 2x faster than the previous one I published. Should help you do what you wanted.

Comment: @Tadeck My solution takes 0.0279 seconds on my machine.

Comment: @ealfonso: Your solution raises `NameError`. I am willing to compare it, if you will make it work.

Answer (score 7):

Cheap way to do this:

```
for i in xrange(LOW, HIGH):
    s = str(i)
    if len(set(s)) == len(s):
        # number has unique digits
```

This uses a `set` to collect the unique digits, then checks to see that there are as many unique digits as digits in total.

Comment: This solution will be faster than Tadeck's one if LOW and HIGH are similar numbers. (e.g. 0.9 * HIGH < LOW < HIGH)

Answer (score 4):

List comprehension will work a treat here (logic stolen from nneonneo):

```
[x for x in xrange(LOW,HIGH) if len(set(str(x)))==len(str(x))]
```

And a timeit for those who are curious:

```
> python -m timeit '[x for x in xrange(10000,100000) if len(set(str(x)))==len(str(x))]'
10 loops, best of 3: 101 msec per loop
```

Comment: In modern Python

`(x for x in range(10000,100000) if len(y:=str(x))==len(set(y))`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer from scratch:

```
def permute(L, max_len):
    allowed = L[:]
    results, seq = [], range(max_len)
    def helper(d):
        if d==0:
            results.append(''.join(seq))
        else:
            for i in xrange(len(L)):
                if allowed[i]:
                    allowed[i]=False
                    seq[d-1]=L[i]
                    helper(d-1)
                    allowed[i]=True
    helper(max_len)
    return results

A = permute(list("1234567890"), 5)
print A
print len(A)
print all(map(lambda a: len(set(a))==len(a), A))
```

It perhaps could be further optimized by using an interval representation of the allowed elements, although for n=10, I'm not sure it will make a difference. I could also transform the recursion into a loop, but in this form it is more elegant and clear.

Edit: Here are the timings of the various solutions

- 2.75808000565    (My solution)
- 8.22729802132    (Sol 1)
- 1.97218298912    (Sol 2)
- 9.659760952      (Sol 3)
- 0.841020822525   (Sol 4)

Comment: Ok, to make your solution comparable with other solutions, could you: 1) fix the exceptions and make it work without necessity for modifications, 2) use [`timeit.timeit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) for measuring the time, 3) make sure it produces proper results (after fixing exception), 4) maybe also run `timeit.timeit()` on all the solutions for comparison?

Comment: I made a mistake when copying from the interpreter, calling "helper" instead of "permute". It is fixed now.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, it certainly can be improved, I just did not find it amusing enough to do it myself. But I am looking forward to see what will be your approach. In the meantime I also removed the downvote that I made due to issues with your solution. Plus, I would not call `itertools` an _external library_, as it is part of [standard library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/).

Answer (score 0):

```
no_list=['115432', '555555', '1234567', '5467899', '3456789', '987654', '444444']
rep_list=[]
nonrep_list=[]
for no in no_list:
    u=[]
    for digit in no:
        # print(digit)
        if digit not in u:
            u.append(digit)
    # print(u)

    #iF REPEAT IS THERE
    if len(no) != len(u):
        # print(no)
        rep_list.append(no)
    #If repeatation is not there
    else:
        nonrep_list.append(no)
print('Numbers which have no repeatation are=',rep_list)
print('Numbers which have repeatation are=',nonrep_list)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.